# Landsat 8 band combinations aren't appearing the way they should in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, landsat-8, digital-image-processing, image-analysis

I did all the right steps of combining 7 of Landsat 8 bands into one .tif in ArcMap but the combinations aren't just appearing the way they should, attached picture related.

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the steps you took to combine bands?

Comment: What is the issue, is it the grey northwestern part? And is the issue data specific?

Comment: @Yogi The issue here is that the combinations of bands I'm having here aren't showing in the right colors, Water bodies in Natural Color combination shouldn't reflect that dark color, nor should the bare lands reflect that bluish turquoise..and same goes  for the color infrared band combination that's showing forrests and vegetation in general in blue..

Comment: @Aaron I simply used the Image Analysis tool, selected the 7 bands that I wanted to combine, and finally clicked the Composite Bands button.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.